# Boostrap 3 input with addon and help block

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap CSS 3.3.1, I got a little problem with an input with an addon and a help block.

Just see the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/L8cyqoL1/1/

Tested on Firefox / Chrome. Is the markup wrong ? I tried "input-group" ... as class without success

Here is the markup :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="control-label col-md-3">Titre de la page</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            @
        </div>
        <input type="text" value="Value test" class="form-control input-xxlarge" id="title" name="title" size="46" />
            <span class="help-block">Help Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just take the `help-block` outside the `input-group` as it's not part of it. you should also avoid mixing `input-group` with `col-*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="control-label col-sm-3">Titre de la page</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title"  class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [**this updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zeroskillz/L8cyqoL1/5/)

(stretch the preview pane to see the column support)

Comment: Ok seems to work in this way, thanks for for the fiddle. It just need a new div container in the DOM :( .

Comment: This doesn't work if you need your input to be narrow, but a hint wide.

Answer (score 2):

Its fine to go with the accepted answer, but if you still need `help-block` inside the `input-group` (I needed it to support my working javascript to show inline errors) there is a workaround that would fix the issue and has cross browser support.

```
.input-group .help-block{
  display: table-row;
}
```

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L4joxj90/2/
*(this only has a limitation that we can't use the input-group-addon on the left side of the input field)*

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. In my own markup `help-block` is inside `input-group` in multiple templates so changing markup is tedious. Your answer spared me the stress. Thanks!!!